# Android service won't stop?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-service, background-service

I want to add a background service to my Xamarin.Forms app to fetch some data from the server every X minutes.. so I added a BroadcastReceiver, a service and an alarm manager to do the job, and the service start successfully with a button click, but when I try to stop the service it won't stop !

**this the class to turn on/off the service.**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(Notifications))]
namespace FleetDesigner.Droid
{
class Notifications : Activity, IAndroidNotifications
{
    Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;

    public void StartNotificationsService()
    {
        //Start Notifications Service
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(NotificationsService));
        context.StartService(myIntent);

        //Show Snackbar message
        Activity activity = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;
        Android.Views.View activityRootView = activity.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
        Snackbar.Make(activityRootView, "Notifications activées", Snackbar.LengthLong).Show();
    }

    public void StopNotificationsService()
    {
        //Stop Notifications Service
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(NotificationsService));
        context.StopService(myIntent);

        //Show Snackbar message
        Activity activity = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;
        Android.Views.View activityRootView = activity.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
        Snackbar.Make(activityRootView, "Notifications désactivées", Snackbar.LengthLong).Show();
    }

}
}
```

**and this is the service class**

```
namespace FleetDesigner.Droid
{
[Service
    (Name = "com.fleet.app.NotificationsService",
     Process = "com.fleet.app.NotificationsService",
     Label = "Service Notifications"
    )]

class NotificationsService : Service
{
    AlarmManager manager;
    Intent myIntent;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    //[return: GeneratedEnum]
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        //return base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        manager = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);

        myIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(NotificationsAlarm));
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, 0);

        manager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + 1000, 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);


        return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
        pendingIntent.Cancel();
        manager.Cancel(pendingIntent);
    }

}
}
```

**and finally, this is the broadcast receiver (the logic of the service is just to show a local notification)**

```
namespace FleetDesigner.Droid
{
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
public class NotificationsAlarm : BroadcastReceiver
{
    static Random random = new Random();
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        //showNotifications(context, intent);
        int m = random.Next(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
        var title = "Title";
        var channelName = "TestChannel";
        string channelID = "TestChannel";
        string OverSpeedChannelName = "OverSpeedChannel";

        string notificationChannel = channelName;

        using (var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(context))
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                NotificationChannel channel = null;
                if (channel == null)
                {
                    channel = new NotificationChannel(channelName, channelName, NotificationImportance.Default)
                    {
                        LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public
                    };
                    channel.SetShowBadge(true);
                    notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
                }
                channel.Dispose();

                NotificationChannel overspeedchannel = null;
                if (overspeedchannel == null)
                {
                    overspeedchannel = new NotificationChannel(OverSpeedChannelName, OverSpeedChannelName, NotificationImportance.Default)
                    {
                        LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Secret
                    };
                    overspeedchannel.SetShowBadge(true);
                    notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(overspeedchannel);
                }
                overspeedchannel.Dispose();
            }

            var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelID)
                   .SetContentTitle("Title "+m)
                   .SetContentText("Notification Content")
                   .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_action_map)
                   .SetShowWhen(false)
                   .SetChannelId(notificationChannel);

            var notification = notificationBuilder.Build();
            notificationManager.Notify(m, notification);
        }
    }
}
```

So, as I said the only problem in this code is.. the notifications (background service) never stops even when I call stopService() !

Any suggestions please ? thanks

Comment: you need to keep a reference to the instance of the service that you started and then call stop on that same instance.  You are currently create a new instance and attempting to stop it

Comment: hey @Jason thanks, how can I save the instance ? you know this service must run even after I close the application... so can I save the instance and get it again after closing/reopening the application ? thnx

Comment: I may be mistaken - looking at the docs it seems like you might be using StopService correctly